# Django How to get the current user in my forms class

Tags: python, django

I want to get the current user logged in my forms.py class for show his biography in a CharField (with placeholder or value)

i've tried the **init** method but it doesn't work for me idk what i'm doing wrong ...

here is my form class

```
class ProfileSettingsForm(forms.Form):
    avatar = forms.ImageField(required=False)
    description = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=230, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={"value": "here i want the description of the current user"}))
```

---

with **init**

```
class ProfileSettingsForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = user
        super(ProfileSettingsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    avatar = forms.ImageField(required=False)
    description = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=230, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={"value": self.user}))
```

---

I tried this method

```
class ProfileSettingsForm(forms.Form):

    user = None

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = user
        super(ProfileSettingsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    avatar = forms.ImageField(required=False)
    description = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=230, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={"value": self.user}))
```

but it return None

---

in my views.py:

```
form = forms.ProfileSettingsForm(user=request.user)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Class-Based Views you can override the `get_form_kwargs` method.

**views.py**

```py
# View might not be the correct class for you to inherit from, it's more a example. Having said that, you'd probably use CreateView
class YourView(View):
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        form = super().get_form_kwargs()
        form['user'] = self.request.user
        return form
```

**forms.py**

```py
class ProfileSettingsForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = user
        super(ProfileSettingsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    avatar = forms.ImageField(required=False)
    description = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=230, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={"value": self.user}))
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. but i'm sorry, i don't use class based views :/ do you have a method for function based view ?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have a function-based view example. Also, it's not fair to downvote an answer because you want something else. If it's not helpful to you, don't use it. Unless the answer is wrong or is unrelated, it shouldn't get downvoted. It's clear that you didn't even tried. Please read the rules.